# Pause audio player when video player starts

Tags: jquery, html5-video, html5-audio

I have an instance of Jplayer (HTML5 audio player for jQuery) and an instance of JW Player (HTML5 video player) on the home page of a website I'm jazzing up for a friend: http://www.creativetuition.co.uk/cgt/index.php

I have not yet been able (with my limited JavaScript knowledge) to successfully get the audio player to pause when the video is played, and preferably vice versa.

I presume I have to use some sort of event 'listener', but really I am struggling and would really appreciate any help you guys can offer.  If you want me to post code just say which bits and I will happily oblige.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the jplayer and jwplayer documentation to identify what I needed to do.  This is the script that I used and put at the bottom of the appropriate page.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  jwplayer('mediaspace').onPlay(function () {

  $('#jquery_jplayer_2').jPlayer("pause");
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This one

```
$(function(){ 
    $("video").prop('muted', true); 
  });
```

...

```
 <video class='0' autoplay="true" src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.webm">
 </video>
```

..also

```
$("video").prop('muted', false);  // Unmutes
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try it tonight.  Pardon my ignorance, but at what point is the JavaScript looking at the audio player and putting it in the corresponding play/pause state in sync with the video player?

Comment: @Audity : Sorry didnt get your comment, The above code looks for the video player on load and uses `muted`  property of the `video` and sets it to true..is that it mutes..DOes it worked for you ?

Comment: Thanks, that's ok.  I think there is a little confusion about what I was asking.  When the page loads, the audio player (top of page) automatically plays.  There is also a video player on the page and when a user plays this video, the audio player continues to play.  Thus, a sound clash.  I want the audio player to stop when the video starts, and vice-versa.

Comment: Hey SJ GJ, I have not solved this problem yet. Do you have anything further to add based on my previous response? Many thanks.